# Show that the co-variance is zero between $\bar{Y}$ and $Y_i - \bar{Y}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a quick question about how to mathematically show this result. Here is the question and my thoughts.

Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ be i.i.d. R.Vs with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and let $\bar{Y}$ be the mean of those R.Vs.  Show that the co variance is zero between $\bar{Y}$ and $Y_i - \bar{Y}$.

Since we are told that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. R.V.s then we also know that $\bar{Y}$ also has the same distribution but is i.i.d correct? Would that not imply that the co-variance is zero between $\bar{Y}$ and $Y_i - \bar{Y}$ since this is simply a linear combination of R.V.s that are already independent? I am confused about how to mathematically show this however and help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

---

EDIT:

While doing the problem, another question arose. It appears that $E(\bar{Y})$ = $\bar{Y}$ but how can that be if $\bar{Y}$ = $ (1\div n)$ $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ ? If we take the expectation of this second value don't we get $\mu$? But how could $\mu$ = $\bar{Y}$ ?

---

EDIT #2:

So I have been solving the problem with various updates and here is where I am stuck now:

We start here:

$$\text{cov} (\bar{Y}, Y_i - \bar{Y})$ = $E[(\bar{Y}-E(\bar{Y})) * (Y_i-\bar{Y}-E(Y_i-\bar{Y}))]$$

so simplifying this expression according to the fact that $E(\bar{Y})$ = $\mu$ gives the following:
$$\bar{Y}\mu - \bar{Y^2} - \mu^2 + \mu\bar{Y}$$ 
I am confused whether or not this equals zero. I would also greatly appreciate an explanation of how $\mu$ and $\bar{Y}$ relate in practical purposes. Thanks so much!

Comment: You have simplified incorrectly. @Roger has posted a correct solution below. The important observation is that $\text{Cov}[Y_i,Y_j]$ is zero if $i\neq j$ and $\sigma^2$ if $i=j$. Also, write $\bar Y$ in terms of the $Y_i$ and use the multilinear of the covariance operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the question posed in the edit, it is *not* true that $E[\bar Y] = \bar Y$.  Instead, $\bar Y$ is an estimator of $E[Y]$. It is a linear combination of $n$ i.i.d. random variables. $E[\bar Y]=E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[Y_i]=\frac{1}{n}\cdot n\mu = \mu$.

To see the computation of the covariance, replace the first $\bar{Y}$ with its definition and apply linearity to get

$$\text{Cov}[\bar{Y}, Y_i - \bar{Y}] = \frac1n\sum_j \text{Cov}[Y_j,Y_i] - \frac1n \sum_j \text{Cov}[Y_j,\bar{Y}]$$

Note that $\text{Cov}[Y_j,Y_i]$ is zero for $j\neq i$ and is $\text{Var}[Y_i] = \sigma^2$ for $j=i$, so the first sum is just $\frac1n \sigma^2$. So we now have

$$\text{Cov}[\bar{Y}, Y_i - \bar{Y}] = \frac1n \sigma^2 - \frac1n\sum_j \text{Cov}[Y_j,\bar{Y}]$$

Now do it again, working on the second instance of $\bar{Y}$. Replace the second $\bar{Y}$ with its definition and apply linearity again to get

$$\text{Cov}[\bar{Y}, Y_i - \bar{Y}] = \frac1n \sigma^2 - \frac1n \sum_j \left( \frac1n \sum_k \text{Cov}[Y_j,Y_k]\right)$$

Just as before, $\text{Cov}[Y_j,Y_k]$ is zero for $k\neq j$ and is $\text{Var}[Y_j] = \sigma^2$ for $k=j$, so we now have

$$\text{Cov}[\bar{Y}, Y_i - \bar{Y}] = \frac1n \sigma^2 - \frac1n \sum_j \left( \frac1n \sigma^2\right)$$

Since each of the $n$ inner summands is the same, we have

$$\text{Cov}[\bar{Y}, Y_i - \bar{Y}] = \frac1n \sigma^2 - \frac1n  (n \cdot \frac1n \sigma^2) = \frac1n \sigma^2 - \frac1n \sigma^2 = 0$$
as desired.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the linear combination part perfectly. I am however confused as to how the $cov$ is zero and how these variables are related in practice. An explanation in plain English would greatly help with my understanding of the sampling distribution and the related :)

Comment: The idea is this. You have a RV $Y$. It has a definite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Those are specific numerical values, but you might not know what they are. How do you estimate $\mu$ using $n$ random samples of $Y$? The best estimator is $\bar Y =\frac{1}{n}\sum_j Y_j$. This is not a number, it is a rule for combining RVs that are i.i.d. Like $Y$. To get a numerical estimate, you can use a specific set of values of the RVs and combine them according to that rule. Each time you perform this sampling you can get a different set of numbers and so a different estimate of $\mu$...

Comment: ...but you use the same rule to combine them each time. So $\bar Y$ is itself random, so it makes sense to speak of $E[\bar Y]$ and so forth.

Comment: I edited my original answer (again) to include the computation of the covariance in a way that may make it more obvious what's going on. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! I understand now! I really appreciate the help from everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the formula for Covariance.
$$
Cov(x,y) = \mathrm{E}\left[\left(X-\mathrm{E}(X)\right)\left(Y-\mathrm{E}(Y)\right)\right]
$$
For your case
$$
Cov(x,y) = \mathrm{E}\left[\left(\bar{Y}-\mathrm{E}(\bar{Y})\right)\left(Y-\bar{Y}-\mathrm{E}(Y-\bar{Y})\right)\right] = \mathrm{E}\left[0\cdot\left(Y-\bar{Y}\right)\right] = 0 
$$
Here I used the fact that $E(\bar{Y})= \bar{Y}$ since it is a constant value.

Does that help?

Comment: $\bar Y$ and ${\rm E}[\bar Y]$ are not equal in general.  I don't know why you think they are.  The former is a statistic and is random; the latter is equal to the population mean, which we are told is $\mu$

Comment: @heropup very true.

Comment: So if $\bar{Y}$ and $E[\bar{Y}]$ are not equal, does that make Chinny84's answer invalid?

Comment: nicefella: Depends if your $\bar{Y}$ is the mean over all elements of $Y_{1}...Y_{n}$? In the question you said it was. If as heropop was eluding to this was not the case, then the sample mean will vary depending on how you sample the data. However, as $n\rightarrow\infty$ or the limit of the population data set, $\bar{Y}\rightarrow \mu$.

Comment: If $\bar Y$ were the expectation of $Y_i$, it wouldn't be called $\mu$ too would it?

Comment: Yes, in this question and as I intended it (sorry if this was confusing) $\bar{Y}$ was meant to be the mean over all the elements of $Y_1 ... Y_n$ as you suggested. Thanks so much, thus $\bar{Y}$ is also termed: the sampling distribution of the sample mean correct? Yes Roger, I realized :) Thanks so much to the both of you!

Comment: The answer posed by @Chinny84 is incorrect, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Remark that $\text{cov}(\bar Y, Y_i - \bar Y) $ does not depend of $i$,
$$ \forall i, \ \sum_{j=1}^n \text{cov}(\bar Y, Y_j - \bar Y) = n \ \text{cov}(\bar Y, Y_i - \bar Y).  $$
The covariance is bilinear, so
$$ \frac 1 n \sum_{j=1}^n \text{cov}(\bar Y, Y_j - \bar Y) = \text{cov}(\bar Y, \frac 1 n \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j - \bar Y) = \text{cov}(\bar Y,0) = 0.$$